# Synchronizing data between Google Sheets and MS Excel using Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I open MS-Word file in Google Document and edit it. But changes wasn't reflected to original MS-Word file. Please tell me how to fix this. Is there any way through API?

Comment: Just want to confirm , are you using this for backup purposes?

Comment: There's no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I really liked your question, see if this helps :

you need to edit the file using the following two options

1. Edit the file using Office Compatibility Mode (OCM)
2. Convert the file to Google Docs, Sheets, or Slides.

For using the Office Compatibility Mode (OCM), do the following

Go to : 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/apps

Go to the Extensions "Menu"

Search for --> Office

Install the " Office Editing for Docs, Sheets & Slides" extension

Now go to Google Drive, there go to the settings
and uncheck the Convert Upload option
(Convert uploaded files to Google Docs editor format)

However if the doc is heavily formated, this may not be 
a good way to edit it.

Ref: See the link below
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odjJBYpJmxs

Comment: Thanks Salinir for  response.But i can't keep this for all users from my application.User can't take this risk like that wright...?.Is there any way through API....?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry i didn't see the last part of your question where you have asked for API. I have not done this before ...
however ever when i check in the web,,i didn;t see any API like Google Docs API, I can see the Google Sheets and Google Slides API though in the RESTful APIs that Google is providing.

So Maybe can  redesigning you app a little using Google Picker of Google Drive API, may help OR use the paid Google Apps for work https://apps.google.com/products/docs/

Some one else , in this forum may reply with better answer.